# SpringBoot Junit Testing RestControllers

Tags: spring, testing, junit, spring-restcontroller

I need to know if testing only restControllers in spring boot application is enough in unit testing or better to test all the classes independently?.

Comment: Well, if all your code is in controllers, that will get you 100% code coverage, whuch is great. If 1% of your code is in controllers, that will get you 1% code coverage, and you will thus have no idea if the remaining 99% of the code works as expected. So. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple and 'right' answer. You should decide it for yourself.

First of all it worth to mention two things:

- Framework for testing controllers: [Spring MockMvc framework](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/), it is for integration testing of Spring web applications. It can test single controller (with mocked service layer) and entire application (including service and database layers, with embedded databases).
- Article answering which tests you should have: [Test pyramid conception](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html) (in short you should have a lot of unit tests and a little of integration tests).

My personal preference is to cover the 'happy path' by integration tests (covering service and DB layers).

Then I cover by unit tests classes with complex logic (not all classes).

In my practice most of applications are quite simple, and I found that I have a lot of integration tests and not so many unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Max Fariskov is right, and I can add two remarks.

1. Unit tests work properly when you launch them really often. After
   every compile is often enough :). That's why every unit test must chek one little part of the functionality. Testing the whole controller is a too complex task.

   - Decouple business logic from a controller,
   - Put it into service,
   - Test service with its own unit test
   - Mock service functionality in your controller - test and check only
     controller behavior.
2. Unit tests are fast but the integration tests are slooow and complex. So it is a good idea to split them into different groups. Execute your unit tests often and your integration tests only when you have to.

I'm doing it with "profiles":

- Create two empty interfaces. For example:

  public interface UnitTest {}
  public interface IntegrationTest {}
- Mark your test classes with proper annotation

  @Category({IntegrationTest.class})
  public class MySlowAndComplexServiceTest {}

  @Category({UnitTest.class})
  public class MyFastServiceTest {}

  - create two profiles in you .pom

  unitTests
      
          true
      
      
          
              
                  maven-surefire-plugin
                  2.19.1
                  
                      UnitTest.class
                  
              
          
      


      integrationTests
      
          false
      
      
          
              
                  maven-surefire-plugin
                  2.19.1
                  
                      IntegrationTest.class,UnitTest.class

It's done.
Your unit test will be executed by default and you can switch on "integrationTests" profile to activate you integration tests at any moment.